# Jest fn undefined when used as an object property

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a class where I am trying to mock an object and its properties

```
intercept(context: ExecutionContext) {
  const response = contect.switchToHttp().getResponse() // need to mock this chain

  if (response.headersSent) { // to test this path
    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

If I 'mock' the dependency using a normal object literal and some anonymous functions, everything works as expected

```
const executionContext = {
  switchToHttp: () => executionContext, // calls itself to simulate 'this' chaining
  getRequest: () => {
    return {
      url: undefined,
      method: undefined,
      headers: undefined,
      connection: {
        remoteAddress: undefined,
        remotePort: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  getResponse: () => {
    return {
      headersSent: true, // but i want an easy way to change this in tests without using a factory
      append: () => undefined
    }
  }
} as unknown as ExecutionContext

it('test', () => {
  const response = myclass.intercept(executionContext);

  expect(response).toBeTrue()
});
```

When I try and mock some of the properties using `jest.fn()` I get strange results.

```
const getResponseSpy = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    headersSent: false,
    append: () => undefined
  }
});

const executionContext = {
  switchToHttp: () => executionContext,
  getRequest: () => {
    return {
      url: undefined,
      method: undefined,
      headers: undefined,
      connection: {
        remoteAddress: undefined,
        remotePort: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  getResponse: getResponseSpy // easier way to change this
} as unknown as ExecutionContext
```

at this point in my code, I get a response as `undefined`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headersSent' of undefined
```

and if I do something like `getResponse: () => getResponseSpy` then `response` inside my code is a Jest mock object rather than the mocked implementation. This of course lacks the `headersSent` property.

I feel like I'm doing something basic wrong. I've tried using

```
switchToHttp: jest.fn().mockResturnThis()
```

But it doesn't change anything. The jest spy inside the object doesn't seem to return its mock implementation

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[mockFn.mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) should work.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
interface ExecutionContext {
  switchToHttp(): ExecutionContext;
  getResponse(): ExecutionContext;
  headersSent: boolean;
}

export const myclass = {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    if (response.headersSent) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { myclass } from './';

describe('67837058', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const executionContext = {
      switchToHttp: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      getResponse: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      headersSent: true,
    };
    const response = myclass.intercept(executionContext);
    expect(response).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67837058/index.test.ts (8.387 s)
  67837058
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      80 |       50 |     100 |      80 |                   
 index.ts |      80 |       50 |     100 |      80 | 15                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.273 s
```

Comment: I clarified the question, i don't think its about chaining